# Author-number citation with elsarticle

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib, elsarticle

With the `elsarticle` class, how can I achieve author-number citations?

This is what I need:

```
Smith and Dow [1] wrote
```

Using

```
\citep{SmithDow} wrote
```

only prints

```
[1] wrote
```

and

```
\citet{SmithDow} wrote
```

prints

```
(author?) [1] wrote
```

This journal does not use author-year style, so

```
Smith and Dow (2015) wrote
```

is not a solution.

I cannot change the options to `natbib` directly because `elsarticle` loads it automatically.

Answer (score 13):

Use

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
```

instead of

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
```

Then

```
\citet{SmithDow} wrote
```

will print

```
Smith and Dow [1] wrote
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer by @AlexanderGelbukh:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
```

and put this into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\doi}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\bibinfo\@secondoftwo
    \urlstyle{rm}%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{%
      doi:\discretionary{}{}{}%
      \nolinkurl{#1}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

This adds support for `doi` fields. Source: https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-August/032152.html

The support for `doi` fields was already done in `elsarticle-num.bst` by [urlbst](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/urlbst/) according to the header of that file. This patch is not (yet) done for `elsarticle-num-names`.