# i need the command for citing my reference with author and year e.g magda(1980)

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I used the following commands to do so but could not able to produce name of author with year. I only produced author name.

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{thebibliography}
    \bibitem[Magda(1980)]{ref1}Magda C.G.(1980).Circular balanced repeated measurements designs, \textit{Comm. Statist.Theory   Methods} \textbf{9}, 1901-1918.
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Did you use any `\cite` commands? Try with `\citet{ref1}`.

Comment: yes i used it but its not giving me required result

Comment: its giving me Magda[1]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal *compilable* example so that we can reproduce your problem? Includes the documentclass, the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` commands etc.

Comment: You can edit your code into the question with the `edit` button below your question.

Comment: i am unable to edit my latex program here

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199442/117534, let me know if the answer helps.

Comment: thanks for it but i want to write wolf et.al.,(2009)

Comment: Use `\citet{}` instead of `\citep{}`

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two different bibliography systems here. If you want to write the bibliography manually in a `thebibliography` environment, there are a couple of things to change:

- Remove `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`
- Add the mandatory argument to the `thebibliography` environment, i.e. `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`. (If you have 10 or more citations, use e.g. `99` instead of `9`.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[round,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\citep{ref1} \citet{ref1}
\section*{\refname}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem[Magda(1980)]{ref1} Magda C.G.(1980). Circular balanced repeated measurements designs, \textit{Comm. Statist.Theory   Methods} \textbf{9}, 1901--1918.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i think there is clash of package between elsarticle and using natbib

Comment: @muhammaddaniyal Oh, right, you were using that class, sorry. Use `\documentclass[round,authoryear]{elsarticle}` and remove `natbib`.

Comment: thanks a lot.. you made it quite easy for me to understand.. thanks once again